# How to find index of a specific element?

Tags: javascript, html

I am working with JavaScript. I have made a function which is called when the specific element in a document is clicked. And on click of that element I want to return the index of its parent.

**Below is my code**

```
var fbEl = document.getElementsByClassName("_42nr");
var fbPost = document.getElementsByClassName("_5jmm _5pat _3lb4 s_1qgkos469b");
var fbPostUrl = document.getElementsByClassName("_5pb8 _8o _8s lfloat _ohe");

var h = '<a href="" ><div style="float:left;font-weight:bold;cursor:pointer;height:14px;color:#4b4f56;" class="myprivateLikeButton"><img src="http://bitbaysolutions.com/Icons/icon_like.png" style="width:17px;height:17px;margin-right:7px;float:left;margin-top:-4px;">Private Like</div></a>';

for (var i = 0; i < fbEl.length ; i++) {
    if((fbEl[i].children.length<=3) && !(fbEl[i].firstChild.innerText.toLowerCase()=="private like")){
        fbEl[i].insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin',h);
    }
}

document.addEventListener("click",function(e){
    var ev = e.target; 
    if(ev.innerText=="Private Like"){

        var liked = "http://bitbaysolutions.com/Icons/icon_liked.png";
        ev.firstChild.setAttribute("src",liked) ;
        ev.style.color="#e20505";


        alert(fbEl.indexOf(ev.parentElement.parentElement));

    };
});
```

The `ev` return the element that is clicked. And the `ev.parentElement.parentElement` return the parent element of that specific child which is clicked. There are number of elements with same class. So I want to get the index of that specific child parent. My method is not working, which I have shown. I need this to be done in javascript.

Comment: are u using jquery?

Comment: No pure javascript

Comment: @Liam I tried that too, but as I said I am using extension, so that is why I want to work with pure javascript

Comment: Please read [What are tags, and how should I use them?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Comment: Sure, Thanks @Liam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are able to get **parentElement**, you can use **class selector** for getting the index of respective **parent element**.

Below is a sample snippet.

```
var idx =$(".your_class").index($(ev.parentElement.parentElement));
```

If you want to achieve this purely in JavaScript, then you can follow below logic :

```
var allElems = document.getElementsByClassName("your_class_name");
var index=-1;
for(var i=0;i<allElems.length;i++){
    if(allElems[i]===ev.parentElement.parentElement){
         index=i;
         break;
    }
}
```

Now you will have index of the parent element.

Comment: is it possible with pure javascript !

Comment: Great, Thanks for your answer !

Comment: the program I have written is and with your combination I am getting what I need but its refreshing the page why is that

Comment: If click is performed on **a** tag then you need to remove its default behaviour by calling preventDefault.

Comment: Thank you very much Buddy !

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to get index of parent element:

Html structure:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">btn 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">btn 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">btn 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">btn 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">btn 5</a></li>
</ul>
```

Vanilla JavaScript:

```
let links = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('ul > li > a'));
let parentElements = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('ul > li'));

links.forEach(link => {
    link.addEventListener('click', e => {
        let index = parentElements.indexOf(e.target.parentElement);
        console.log(index);
    });
});
```

And here's working **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/214uykzv/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

***use this***

```
alert($("a").index($(ev).parents("a")))
```

Comment: IS IT possible with pure javascript

Comment: TBF @Nadeem if you'd tagged this question correctly in the first place this wouldn't be an issue!

Comment: @krishnar : This might answer the question. Would you mind extending it, for fellow programmers, to understand how exactly it helps to solve the problem?